# Adding arrowheads to a piecewise function

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{-x^2, x < 1}, {x + 1, x >= 1}}], {x, -2, 3},
  PlotStyle -> Blue,
  Epilog -> {
    Blue, Arrowheads[{-0.02, 0.02}],
    PointSize[Large],
    Point[{{1, -1}, {1, 2}}],
    {White, PointSize[Medium], Point[{1, -1}]}
    },
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 3}, {-4, 4}},
  GridLines -> {Range[-2, 3], Range[-4, 4]},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  ImageSize -> 300] /. Line -> Arrow
```

Which gives this image:

[image]

How can I adjust the image so the arrow on the parabolic part is at its left end?

Thanks.

Comment: change `Line -> Arrow` to `Line[a__] :> Arrow[If[Last@First@a < 2, Reverse@a, a]]` or `Line[a__] :> Arrow[If[First@First@a < 1, Reverse@a, a]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a bit of a hack..

```
ipart = 0; 
Plot[Piecewise[{{-x^2, x < 1}, {x + 1, x >= 1}}], {x, -2, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Epilog -> {Blue, Arrowheads[{-0.02, 0.02}], PointSize[Large], 
    Point[{{1, -1}, {1, 2}}], {White, PointSize[Medium], 
     Point[{1, -1}]}}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 3}, {-4.5, 4}}, 
  GridLines -> {Range[-2, 3], Range[-4, 4]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ImageSize -> 300] /. 
 Line[xx_] :> {++ipart; If[ipart == 1, Arrow[Reverse@xx], Arrow[xx]]}
```

[image]

Comment: Quite helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Using custom `Arrowheads` (instead of `Epilog`) may be slightly  more flexible:

```
ah1 = Arrowheads[{{-0.05}, {0.015, 1, Graphics@{EdgeForm[Blue], White, Disk[]}}}];
ah2 = Arrowheads[{{0.05, 1}, {0.015, 0, Graphics@ Disk[]}}];
pw = Piecewise[{{-x^2, x < 1}, {x + 1, x >= 1}}];
```

This can be used with a combination of `MeshFunctions` and `MeshShading`:

```
Plot[pw, {x, -2, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  MeshFunctions -> {# &}, Mesh -> {{1}}, MeshShading -> {ah1, ah2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},  PlotRange -> {{-2, 3}, {-4, 4}}, 
  GridLines -> {Range[-2, 3], Range[-4, 4]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> .01] /. Line -> Arrow
```

or in `PlotStyle` after breaking up the `Piecewise` pieces into two `ConditionalExpression`s:

```
Plot[Evaluate[ConditionalExpression @@@ pw[[1]]], {x, -2, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, ah1], Directive[Blue, ah2]},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 3}, {-4, 4}}, 
  GridLines -> {Range[-2, 3], Range[-4, 4]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> .01] /. Line -> Arrow
```

to get

[image: Mathematica graphics]